# which thread does a new thread sees as 'parent'

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

i have a winForm app. The program.cs launches form1 and another thread sThread. I call a function from sThread on form1 that creates a new thread z . Which of the two(form1 and sThread) will z consider as parent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A thread doesn't have a parent.  The notion is meaningless.  The 'container' for threads is the process.

Comment: so if i create a thread B from thread A, if thread A closes the thread B will go on with no problem ? (i.e. i need a message-box-thread for some events and was wondering if i close the thread that created the messagebox-thread , will the messagebox-threads go on with no problem ? )

Comment: That's correct.  In general *never* display message boxes on a thread.  They have a nasty habit of disappearing behind another window.

Comment: @Aaron: that's within the Debugger.

Comment: @John Just tossing it out there...my assumption is the OP had nothing to do with EnvDTE...but it never hurts to add more info... actually it can hurt but I didn't think it hurt in this instance. :)

Comment: @Aaron: it wasn't more info. It was of no value, except to someone working in the debugger.

Comment: @John As I am no expert in EnvDTE my understanding was that it could be used for automation purposes within Visual Studio itself (not UI automation)...which would be outside the scope  of working in the debugger. Is that not accurate?

Comment: @Aaron: please go read up on that. You are mistaken, and it won't take you long to realize it.

Comment: @John The EnvDTE namespace states.."EnvDTE is an assembly-wrapped COM library containing the objects and members for Visual Studio core automation." glancing at the members there is access to items such as Macros...which states..."The Macros object allows add-ins to programmatically control the macro recorder and manipulate macro recording." So clearly I am missing something...if you have information aside from the MSDN please point me to it.

Comment: @Aaron - why don't you ask a question about it?

Comment: @Aaron: Property Value
Type: EnvDTE.Debugger
A Debugger object.

Comment: @Aaron: If I were you, I'd either give up now, or else stop talking and start reading. Posting the link was a good thing; continuing once you've been shown to be mistaken is starting to be embarassing.

Comment: @John Miscommunication; I was speaking to the entire EnvDTE lib, not the Debugger property where the Thread.Parent originates from. Missed Type: EnvDTE.Debugger in the docs..oh well, all is well now...thanks.

Comment: @John I wanted to understand why. If I need to get embarrassed to learn why, so it goes...

Answer (score 1):

threads have no parent child hiererchy but processes do. so if process A "forks" a process "B" then A is parent of B meaning that A and B can share memory and communicate